# TextMeshPro 3D text glowing?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, textmeshpro

I'm trying to use TextMesh pro with 3D text but in is glowing? I don't have glow on the text, so I don't know why its glowing through the fog in my scene.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/miUlJ.jpg
This image shows what the text looks like in my scene. (The white glowing thing is the text)

Comment: Do you use any post-processing? You probably just forgot to ignore the UI layer for that then

Answer (score 1):

By default, text is not affected by lighting.  It uses unlit shaders.  That's why it appears to be "glowing".

Pretty sure there are also included lit shaders you can switch to in the configuration for your TextMeshPro materials.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try looking at it without selecting the in-game object, or is it constantly going regardless of what you have currently selected? That was my issue, I was only seeing a glow because it highlighted the object I was working with.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).